# How can I customize a custom component using CSS?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am working on a React project and i am stuck on customizing a checkbox to have an orange border and a orange check mark "onchecked".

I have tried using webkit but it doesn't give me desireable results.

[image]

```
.storybook-input--checkbox {
    appearance: none ;
    -moz-appearance: none ;
    -webkit-appearance: none ;
  border: 2px solid #f3533d ;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 24px ;
  width: 24px; }
```

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css help?

Comment: It actually does. Thank you so much.